BTS - binary tree search
I'm trying to create my first BTS in java and I'm having some problems with my code:
I need to create methods for adding items and deleting items from the tree.
This is what I wrote:
@Override
public boolean addItem(ListItem item) {
    if(item == null){
        return false; // nothing is inside
    }
    ListItem currentItem = root;
    while(currentItem != null){
        int comparison = item.compareTo(currentItem);
        if(comparison > 0){
            if(currentItem.next() != null){
                currentItem = currentItem.next();
            }
            else{
                currentItem.setNext(item).setPrevious(currentItem);
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(comparison < 0){
            if(currentItem.previous() != null){
                currentItem = currentItem.previous();
            }
            else{
                currentItem.setPrevious(item).setNext(currentItem);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean removeItem(ListItem item) {
    if (item == null || root == null) {
        return false;
    }
    ListItem currentItem = root;

    while (currentItem != null) {
        ListItem previous = currentItem;
        int comparison = item.compareTo(currentItem);
        if (comparison > 0) {
            if (currentItem.next() != null) {
                currentItem = currentItem.next();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (comparison < 0) {
            if (currentItem.previous() != null) {
                currentItem = currentItem.previous();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if (currentItem == this.root) {
                this.root = currentItem.next();
            } else {
                currentItem.previous().setNext(currentItem.next());
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

}
what's wrong with my my code? it does'nt compile properly and gets stuck. :(
I do not understand how to make the rightlinks and leftlinks refer to the father node.

Which is it, "it doesn't compile properly" (then what diagnostics are emitted by the compiler?) or it "gets stuck"?  I assure you that if it gets stuck then that's because the code is wrong, not because the compiler did not operate properly.

"I do not understand how to make the rightlinks and leftlinks refer to the father node" -- why do you think you need to do?  BSTs can have rootward links, and some do, but they are only required to have leafward links, and many have only those.

i've tried adding the following numbers one after the other:
1- > 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 3
it stops adding after "4" then gets stuck.

Are the "previous" and "next" of your ListItems its child nodes?  That would be unconventional naming. I do see some justification for it, but such naming is likely to confuse people.

Yes, it refers to the child nodes.

Question is how can I delete an item from this tree? what do i need to attach together and how is the whole tree order affected from this change ?

If the code doesn't compile, the question should include a copy of the compiler error message. This should be as text, not as an image. If the code does not compile, you should not attempt to run it. If the compiler produces multiple unrelated error messages, the question is unsuitable for Stack Overflow, because questions here should deal with one issue only, i.e., questions should be narrowly focused.

From the comment above, it seems that you were able to run the program, so your statement "it doesn't compile properly" isn't true. If it didn't compile properly, you wouldn't have anything to run.

If your code compiles cleanly, but doesn't behave the way you expect, the question should make it clear about how it doesn't behave as expected. In general, such questions should include examples. Each example should include input, expected output, and actual output, if any. If an exception is thrown, the question should include an exact copy of the message and stack trace, as text, not as an image. "i've tried adding the following numbers one after the other: 1- > 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 3 it stops adding after "4" then gets stuck." should be in the question body, not a comment.

Hi, איתי גולדשטיין. Welcome to Stack Overflow. My previous comments and comments from others are intended to help you improve the question.  To help you better understand how to use Stack Overflow, I suggest browsing including these resources: Tour, Help Center, and How to Write a Good Question.

If your program gets stuck, it might be in a closed loop. Using a debugger might help find that and possibly other problems.

"I do not understand how to make the rightlinks and leftlinks refer to the father node.": you need a third member for that: two for the two children, one for the parent.

Based on the code presented, I take ListItem's properties previous and next to refer to its child nodes -- previous for the root of the subtree of lesser items, and next for the root of the subtree of greater items.  As I wrote in comments, that's unconventional naming, likely to confuse others.  I suspect it may have confused you, too.
It would be more conventional to use left and right, or something derived from those.  Maybe leftChild and rightChild if you want to exchange a bit of brevity for a bit more clarity.
Having understood that, these lines from addItem() look wrong:
                currentItem.setNext(item).setPrevious(currentItem);

                currentItem.setPrevious(item).setNext(currentItem);

It's unclear what setNext() and setPrevious() return, but the only options that even remotely make sense are the item on which they are invoked or the item that is set as a child.  Either way, you're creating a loop, either currentItem directly back to itself or currentItem to item and item back to currentItem.  That could easily explain subsequent operations on the tree looping indefinitely.  Probably you want just:
                currentItem.setNext(item);

and
                currentItem.setPrevious(item);

.
In that vein, you remark

I do not understand how to make the rightlinks and leftlinks refer to the father node.

Most likely, you don't.  Although binary search trees can have links from children back to parents, that is not essential for standard BST operations, and many BSTs don't have such links.  If your tree had them / wanted them then that would be a different property of the items, not next or previous.
Supposing that you indeed don't have parent links, your removeItem() should track the parent of the current node in a separate variable as it traverses the tree.  It looks like you have a variable previous that might have been intended for this purpose, but you don't use it and it's scope is not suitable.  You probably want something more along these lines:
    ListItem parentItem = null;
    ListItem currentItem = root;

    while (currentItem != null) {
        int comparison = item.compareTo(currentItem);

        if (comparison > 0) {
            parentItem = currentItem;
            currentItem = currentItem.next();
        } else if (comparison < 0) {
            parentItem = currentItem;
            currentItem = currentItem.previous();
        } else {
            // ... remove the node ...
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

You then can (and need to) use parentItem in the actual node removal.
Note also:

your addItem() does not appear to be able to add items to an empty tree, as it will return false without doing anything if the tree root is initially null.

the actual node removal code in the question,

currentItem.previous().setNext(currentItem.next());


is not remotely correct.  Tracking and using the parent item is necessary here, but not sufficient.  Consider what happens to the original right subtree of currentItem.previous().  If it has one (as it well may), that is lost.


